# Unable to use Multi Select property in winform DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView control, Here If i select one row, then press shift key then and then select another row, It is selecting Multiple rows which is expected behaviour..
But my problem is that, If I select row programmatically 
using

```
 myGridView.Rows1.Selected = true;
```

which is visible in UI, But if I press Shift then press another row, it is selecting only one row.
Given below is the code snippet that i am using to bind data to control

[image: Code Snippet]

Comment: "But if I press Shift then press another key". What other key do you press? I rebuilded a simple `DataGridView` in a new application and it seems to work ok. Have you tried that? Just create a clean new application and put only your grid in this app. Is the behaviour still existing?

Comment: @Roman : Sorry I mistyped, another key means another row..  This is working if u select row from UI then multi select using shift Key..

Comment: @MsYvette : Yes ms, I already made multiselect = true..

Comment: Ah, okay. Well, have you tried my suggestion above? Create a new application and only put your `DataGridView` in it and see what happens?

Comment: @Roman : Yes I am trying it, Give me few minutes

Comment: @Roman : Yes Roman, it is working in new application. Actually I am customizing default control to implement multi header in datagridview.. May be this has changed some property because of which it's not working.  It's difficult to debug, Can u suggest me any idea which property i need to set to re-implement this? :(

Comment: Okay, than somethings wrong in your main application. What if you create a new `DataGridView` in your main application and data bind it? Is this working or not?

Comment: Yeah its working, There must be something where I am binding data to datagridview.. I don't what's the root cause, but its only in this datagridview However databinding is same for both datagridview

Comment: If you use the same data binding for two different grid views, it's not the binding which causes problem, otherwise it would cause problems on both gridviews. Have you every heard from "Divide & Conquer"? If the debugger does not help you, you could use this debug method. Just cut part for part out your main application and then test the app. Do this until your application works fine. And then you know which code part causes the problem. If you put some more gridview related code in your question we're maybe able to help you a bit more.

Comment: No,, I am using different data source, In above comment, I actually mean that I am using same way to bind the data to gridview, that is using data table as datasource.
Here What I debugged, If I try to change the state of selected row from true to false, If it throwing exception Argument out of range exception for first time, if i do same again i am able to set.. Actually I am new to this winfoms, I am not able to debug.. :(

Comment: Well, to be sure you get every exception, use [try/catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtd0s8kd(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) block. Note, if you want to select the first row in a collection of items/objects/whatever, you must use index 0. So selecting the first row of your gridview will look like `myGridView.Rows[0].Selected = true;`. If you have only 1 row in your collection and use index 1, it will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException` (just fyi). If you share us your data binding code part, we're maybe able to help you.

Comment: Please find the code snippet..

Comment: @Roman : I have debugged that code, It is happening only if I am hiding the particular column. If i dont hide Particular Column, it works as expected..

I have checked in new datagridview, there it is also working fine even if i hide particular column.

Comment: Is there any difference between your grid views? Does it throw exceptions? Have you used try/catch to get every exception? What happens if you comment `RefreshGrid()` and `RefreshPagination`?

Comment: In refreshGrid(), I am jst managing scrolling index and visible property of columns, and RefreshPagination(), I am jst managing pagination for Gridview which is not part of gridview..

Comment: Have you tried commenting them and then restart the app? What about exceptions? It's hard to help here, try divide & conquer, until your problem disappears, it's the easiest and fastest way here I guess, even if it's annoying.

Comment: Yes, I tried @Roman, What I observed, It is happening bcoz i am hiding PropertyID column..
It is working fine if i hide other column.. PropertyID is the column of Data table..

Comment: If you put your code in a try/catch block, is there any exception thrown? Like `try { // your code } catch(Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }`

Comment: No exception is thrown during data binding.. when i try to set the first row selected, it is giving some exception that i told u earlier.. 
As I told you, it is happening if i am trying to hide to column, for that I have changed column order in data table then I hided the column.. Now its working as expected..

Comment: I dont know how it was not working, but from ur suggestion and question u asked me, helped me a lot to debug in particular scope.. Thanks a lot @Roman.. :))

Comment: Okay cool, glad I could help in some way. Good luck and happy coding :)

Comment: Same to you.. @Roman

Answer (score 0):

Don't hold down the `Shift` key.

You should hold down the `Ctrl` key on your keyboard to select multiple rows.

**Edit:**
If you want to use the `Shift` key to select a range of rows starting from the programmatically selected one.  Then you need to move the `DataGridView.CurrentCell` to the index that was programmatically selected.

This example selects row index 4 and makes it ready for the `Shift` key:

```
myGridView.Rows[4].Selected = true;
myGridView.CurrentCell = myGridView[0, 4];
```

Comment: This is true, if the user wants to select multiple nonconsecutive rows. But if the user wants to select multiple rows, including intermediate rows, using `Shift` is more efficient.

Comment: I understood he wanted nonconsecutive rows.  In that case, he just need to move the current cell to the index that was selected.